# Why does bash caller print different linenumbers in the debug trap

Tags: bash, debugging, bash-trap

I am writing a custom debugger for bash scripts using the **DEBUG trap**. I stumbled upon negative line numbers when printing stacktraces using caller.

It seems like caller's output is different, when I call it inside a trap method which is used from a nested call.

debug.sh:

```
d() {
    if [[ "${BASH_COMMAND}" == echo* ]] ; then
        echo ">> $(caller 0) | $(caller 1) | ${BASH_COMMAND} <<"
    fi
}
shopt -s extdebug
set -o functrace
trap d DEBUG
```

test.sh:

```
echo foo

f() {
    echo bar
}
f

echo end
```

When I call my script with `bash --rcfile debug.sh -i test.sh` I get

```
>> 3 main test.sh |  | echo foo <<
foo
>> -2 f test.sh | 8 main test.sh | echo bar <<
bar
>> 10 main test.sh |  | echo end <<
end
```

To compare

compare.sh:

```
echo() {
    /bin/echo ">> $(caller 0) | $(caller 1) | echo "$@" <<"
    /bin/echo "$@"
}
```

I print the information without a trap `bash --rcfile compare.sh -i test.sh`

```
>> 3 main test.sh |  | echo foo <<
foo
>> 1 f test.sh | 8 main test.sh | echo bar <<
bar
>> 10 main test.sh |  | echo end <<
end
```

There is a similar question [how to get the original caller lineno when executing a function returning a non-zero value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213254/how-to-get-the-original-caller-lineno-when-executing-a-function-returning-a-non) which misses both an explanation for bash's behaviour and a solution working for this scenario.

Assuming bash calculates something wrong in the trap I already tried to recalculate the correct linenumbers by investigating where the function definitions lie, but couldn't find any reasonable way.